# Running SQLQuery by ant script but it is not creating tables

Tags: oracle, ant, sqlplus

As I am new to antscript and sql/oracle therefore I am unable to understand the log that I have got.So could you please tell me by looking into the code that in which direction I should move.Is the connection doesn't set up or its another problem.
    Build.xml for running the ant script is defined below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Hello World Project" default="myTarget">

<target name="myTarget">

<!-- directory where db scritps reside -->
<property name="oracle.scriptPath" value="D:\\ganganshu" />
<!-- path of tnsnames.org file -->
<property name="oracle.tns_alias" value="wind" />
<!-- Oracle user name -->
<property name="oracle.user_name" value="system" />

<!-- Oracle Password -->
<property name="oracle.password" value="manager" />

  <!-- login.sql should have sqlcode exit so failonerror will fail build -->
  <exec executable="sqlplus" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="${oracle.user_name}/${oracle.password}@${tns_alias}"/>
        <arg value="@${oracle.scriptPath}\\SILO1_schema_script.sql"/>
  </exec>
</target>
</project>    


 and my sql script file is defined below


DROP TABLESPACE SILO2 INCLUDING CONTENTS CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;
DROP USER SILO2;

CREATE TABLESPACE SILO2 DATAFILE 'D:\PTC\WINDCHILL_10.2\OCU\ORADATA\WIND\SILO2.DBF' SIZE 8388608 AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 131072 MAXSIZE 32767M LOGGING ONLINE PERMANENT BLOCKSIZE 8192 EXTENT MANAGEMENT LOCAL AUTOALLOCATE DEFAULT NOCOMPRESS  SEGMENT SPACE MANAGEMENT AUTO;

/* USER SQL */ 
CREATE USER SILO2 IDENTIFIED BY SILO2 DEFAULT TABLESPACE "SILO2" TEMPORARY  TABLESPACE "TEMP";

but when i try to run the ant file I am getting this in the command prompt and the 
scheama is not getting created



 [exec]
 [exec] SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Dec 16 11:00:32 2013
 [exec]
 [exec] Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
 [exec]
 [exec] ERROR:
 [exec] ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
 [exec]
 [exec]
 [exec] Enter user-name:
```

and my tnsnames.ora contains this

```
# TNSNAMES.ORA Network Configuration File: D:\temp\OSA92\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

wind =
      (DESCRIPTION =
        (ADDRESS_LIST =
          (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = renault-dev.ptcnet.ptc.com)(PORT = 1521))
        )
        (CONNECT_DATA =
          (SID = wind)
        )
  )

and I have set tns_alias as a property in build.xml only and not anywhere else
```

Comment: You don't appear to be defining the `tnsalias` variable.  You could also try using the `-v` option to ant to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing the script name as an argument, but you aren't preceding it with the `@` symbol [to tell SQL*Plus to run the script](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#sthref432):

```
        <arg value="@${oracle.scriptPath}\\SILO1_schema_script.sql"/>
```

And as @GregHNZ pointed out in a comment, you don't seem to be setting `tnsalias`. Either of those will produce the SQL*Plus usage message you're seeing. Your command line is ending up as:

```
sqlplus system/manager@ D:\ganganshu\SILO1_schema_script.sql
```

rather than:

```
sqlplus system/manager@alias @D:\ganganshu\SILO1_schema_script.sql
```

Also your `oracle.tnsnames` property isn't doing anything. The environment that SQL*Plus runs in needs to have `TNS_ADMIN` set to `D:\\ptc\\Windchill_10.2\ocu\Conf` to be able to use the `tnsnames.ora` file in that directory. You can't pass that on the command line.

---

Based on your update to show the contents of your `tnsnames.ora` file, your `tns_alias` property should be:

```
<property name="oracle.tns_alias" value="wind" />
```

That would make you command line:

```
sqlplus system/manager@wind @D:\ganganshu\SILO1_schema_script.sql
```

... which you can test from the Windows command prompt.

Comment: Hi Alex I have changed according to ur comments as shown above but I am getting new error as mentioned above and i am mapping tns_name to tns_names.ora so is it correct way to do it.?

Comment: @user3069865 - `tns_alias` is an alias defined in the `tnsnames.ora`, not the file itself. The location of the file is in environment variable `TNS_ADMIN`, which holds its parent directory. If the DB is on the same machine and you have `ORACLE_SID` set then you don't need the `@alias` part, but it's all about the environment.

Comment: Hi alex.. sorry for late reply ... my database is in the same system .. so what steps I need to follow and I am getting this error 
 SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.1.0 Production on Mon Dec 16 10:08:05 2013

 Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

 ERROR:
 ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


 Enter user-name:

Comment: What is in your `tnsnames.ora`? Is `TNS_ADMIN` set in your environment, and if so what is it set to? (Please add information to the question, not as comments, as it's hard to read).

Comment: @user3069865 - you use the alias defined in `tnsnames.ora`; I've added an example in the question, and you can test it from the command line. If you knew the service name (rather than SID) then you could bypass `tnsnames.ora` and use 'easy connect', but that's another topic.

Comment: thnx alex for helping me.

Comment: alex 1 more thing If i want to execute multiple sql files than how can I do it because by putting multiple arguments 2nd file is not executing.

Comment: No, subsequent arguments on the command line become positional values (`&1` etc.) in your script. You could have a master `.sql` script that you execute from Ant, and that calls a series of other scripts, using [either `@` or `start`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1210918).